# Keeping track of unnamed objects

Tags: android, libgdx

I want to make a top-down 2d shooting game using libgdx. There will be a lot of bullet objects that I want to keep track of and dispose when they go off the screen. I was thinking that I would use something like

```
static ArrayList<Bullet> bullets;
```

to keep track of my bullets in the **Bullet** class, check this array list for any bullets that are off the screen, dispose of them if they are, and delete that bullet from the ArrayList. I was wondering if this is the best way to do this. It seems like something that should be pretty common and so I wanted to make sure that this is the best way of doing this.

Comment: `static` is debatable, depending on your project setup, but in general, yes, a list of bullets is a typical way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using an [object poo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pool_%28computer_science%29)l is a better approach.

The idea of an object pool is simple and fits perfectly for your needs in this case. The pool handles creating and storing the `Bullet` objects. All you have to do is to call the `obtain` method of the pool when you need a bullet (User shoots) and call the recycle method of the pool for this bullet when it's no longer needed in the game (Goes offscreen).

Here is a [code example](http://code.google.com/p/andengine/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/util/pool/GenericPool.java?r=081b452a22a79e04865e6ef72a60d1ceb3731482) for a pool taken from AndEngine's source. You can use it to learn how it works and make your own pool class (Or use this one).

Comment: Here is pool for libgdx. http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/Pool.html

Comment: Both are not associated with their framework, so you can use them anywhere in any java (Only a few debugging lines in AndEngine's pool depend on the framework.. Delete them)

Comment: I agree with using a pool to minimize object creation, etc. He still needs a list of *active* bullets to iterate through, though, no? Unless you incorporate that into the pool itself, which neither linked pool class shows.

Comment: I've put the code to do this job in my pool code (Of one of my games). It's something game dependant, and you can definitely add it in the pool's code.