# AndEngine - General 2D Side-Scroller Problems

Tags: java, android, andengine

I just started using AndEngine, and it's tough to find good tutorials / documentation.
I am making a 2D side-scroller game, where platforms and walls are generated randomly.
The user can control the player's movement (jumping, walking forward).

I have a few general questions:

How do I get a parallax background to scroll only when the player moves?

Should I set the physics world gravity to nothing, and add the force of gravity to each individual object that actually needs it? I don't want gravity to affect floating platforms/walls.

How do I animate a player when it moves (animated walking)?

What is the best way to go about collision detection (player/enemy, player/wall/platform, etc.)?

Sorry, that may have been a lot to ask at once.
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I get a parallax background to scroll only when the player moves?

I have never used parallax backgrounds, but I guess that the background moves as the camera moves. If the player doesn't move, the camera shouldn't move so the background won't move either.

> Should I set the physics world gravity to nothing, and add the force of gravity to each individual object that actually needs it? I don't want gravity to affect floating platforms/walls.

No, use the gravity. When creating bodies that should be unaffected by forces (Thus immovable) you use the `BodyType.StaticBody` option. Static bodies can not be moved (Only by code).

> How do I animate a player when it moves (animated walking)?

Take a look in the [AnimatedSpritesExample](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineExamples/blob/GLES2/src/org/andengine/examples/AnimatedSpritesExample.java). Basically, to animate a sprite it must be instantiated form the `AnimatedSprite` class and you need to supply it with a `TiledTextureRegion` (Contains several regions, each with a different image). Then, by calling the `animate` method of `AnimatedSprite` class you can start the animation.

> What is the best way to go about collision detection (player/enemy, player/wall/platform, etc.)?

If you plan on using Box2D, you can implement a callback called `ContactListener` which will be called when bodies collide in your `PhysicsWorld`.

If you don't plan on using Box2D, you can use AndEngine's methods for collision detection. 
Here is an [example](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineExamples/blob/GLES2/src/org/andengine/examples/CollisionDetectionExample.java).

Comment: Ok you bring up another thing I'm trying to understand.  Since my terrain is not predetermined, should I be moving the generated terrain or the camera centered on the player?  I'm not exactly sure how the whole camera thing works.

Comment: The terrain should remain static, and the camera should follow the player (Who moves). As for the camera question: Image your scene is a huge canvas which has many objects drawn on it. Not all of it is shown at the same time. The camera defines which area of that large canvas is shown.

Comment: How do you go about recycling bodies that are not in view of the camera anymore? Once a terrain object moves fully past the left side of the screen, I would like to permanently recycle it.  The player is not allowed to travel backwards.

Comment: maybe something like this: if (terrainObj.getSprite().getX() + terrainObj.getSprite().getWidth() < 0) destroybody();

Comment: Read about object pools: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13253535/keeping-track-of-unnamed-objects/13253707#13253707

Answer (score 2):

Here is about **collision** filters: [here](http://www.aurelienribon.com/blog/2011/07/box2d-tutorial-collision-filtering/) and [here](http://www.andengine.org/forums/gles2/collision-with-differen-categorybits-and-masks-t6415.html) 
If you asking about collisions overall, than you can do it with sprites: `heroSprite.collidesWith(enemySprite);`
 
if issue with colliding is solved, then you can set **gravity** and body (physics body) only for your hero (for jumping). Or make necessary filters and make walls as static bodies (fixed bodies are not affecting by gravity). 
**Animated hero:**
Load textures: 
`private ITiledTextureRegion hero;`

`BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas heroTextureAtlas = new BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas(gameController.getTextureManager(), 256, 256, TextureOptions.NEAREST);`

`this.hero = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createTiledFromAsset(heroTextureAtlas, gameController.getAssets(), "hero.png", 3, 4);`

`try {
heroTextureAtlas.build(new BlackPawnTextureAtlasBuilder<IBitmapTextureAtlasSource, BitmapTextureAtlas>(0, 0, 0));
            heroTextureAtlas.load();
        }  catch (TextureAtlasBuilderException e) {
            Debug.e(e);
        }`

and use this for animating: `heroSprite.animate(  );` - there is a big choice of method parameters, look what you need.

Sorry for my english, I hope it will help you.

Comment: thank you for the collision filters link. seems pretty handy.