# andengine removing collectable objects like Sprites

Tags: sprite, andengine, tmx

im developing a game using andangine and the tmx and body2d extensions.
i create Objects(sprites) like coins an specific positions while creating my map.
i use a contactlistener to check if the player collides with a coin.

how can i delete this sprite? 
and how can i organize my sprites best?
thanks =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you create a `PhysicsConnector` to connect between your sprites and bodies. Create a list of these physics connectors, and when you decide you should remove a body (And its sprite), do the following:

```
Body bodyToRemove = //Get it from your contact listener
for(PhysicsConnector connector : mPhysicsConnectors) //mPhysicsConnectors is the list of your coins physics connectors.
    if(connector.getBody() == bodyToRemove)
        removeSpriteAndBody(connector); //This method should also delete the physics connector itself from the connectors list.
```

About sprites organization: Coins are re-useable sprite, you shouldn't recreate them every time. You can use an object pool, [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13253535/keeping-track-of-unnamed-objects) a question about this topic.

Comment: ok. i did a method like removeSpriteAndBody but my app crashes when this method gets called. 
 
-25 23:50:51.869: E/AndroidRuntime(15700): FATAL EXCEPTION: UpdateThread
11-25 23:50:51.869: E/AndroidRuntime(15700): java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
11-25 23:50:51.869: E/AndroidRuntime(15700):  at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListIterator.next(ArrayList.java:576)

Comment: try this: Iterator<PhysicsConnectors> iterator = mPhysicsConnectors.iterator();
  while(iterator.hasNext()) {
   connector = iterator.next();
   if (connector.getBody() == needToRemove) {
                            iterator.remove();
                            removeSpriteAndBody(connector);
                        }
                }

Comment: I encountered this problem too when I implemented something similar in my game. Use what Racoon said, it should work.

Comment: still the same error, i guess its my removeSpriteAndBody-method.

protected void removeSpriteAndBody(PhysicsConnector connector) {
physicsConnectors.remove(connector);
scene.detachChild(connector.getShape());

Comment: did you remove iterator before call removeSpriteAndBody?

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to set user data of a body. And in your collision handler you would be able to work with it. Small example:

```
body.setUserData(...);
```

..

```
    public void postSolve(Contact contact, ContactImpulse impulse) {

            ... bodyAType = (...) bodyA.getUserData();
            ... bodyBType = (...) bodyB.getUserData();
            if (bodyAType != null && bodyBType != null) {
               if (bodyAType.getUserData.equals(...)) {
                   //.......do what you need
               }
            }
    }
```